# Searching data in firebase using search bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a material search bar that I use to do a search in my firebase. This search  return values based on a phone number.When i search a phone number that does not exist in firebase it returns me no error , but whenever i search a phone number that match with one that is in firebase I get the following error.Any help on this ?

**Error**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

**Material Search bar code**

```
public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            //when search finish
            //Show result of search adapter
            startSearch(text.toString());
        }
```

**search code**

```
private void startSearch(String text) {
    //create query by name
    Query searchByName = requests.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(text);
    //Create Options with query
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Request> foodOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
            .setQuery(searchByName, Request.class)
            .build();

    Searchadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(foodOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrderViewHolder viewHolder, final int position, @NonNull final Request model) {
            viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(Searchadapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.txtDateTime.setText(model.getDateTime());
}
        @Override
        public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.food_item, parent, false);
            return new OrderViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    };
    Searchadapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(Searchadapter); //Set adapter for Recycler View
```

**Firebase structure**

[image]

Comment: On which exact line of code does this error occur?

Comment: It was a very silly mistake,  I assigned the wrong layout in OnCreateViewHolder.